# Effective way to extract from SSE vector on AMD processors

Tags: sse, simd, amd-processor

I'm looking for an effective way to extract lower 64 bit integer from __m128i on AMD Piledriver. Something like this:

```
static inline int64_t extractlo_64(__m128i x)
{
    int64_t result;
    // extract into result
    return result;
}
```

[Instruction tables](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf) say that common approach - using _mm_extract_epi64() - is ineffective on this processor. It generates PEXTRQ instruction which has a latency of 10 cycles (compared to 2-3 cycles in Intel processors).
Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: It would be useful to see the code around where you are doing this extraction, to get more of a picture of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: It actually lists it as 10 cycles. But a shuffle + movd isn't any better.

Comment: What about `static inline int64_t extract64(__m128i v, uint32_t i) { int64_t t[2]; _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)t,v); return t[i&1];}`?

Comment: I tried `extract64`. According to documentation it generates `MOVDQA` instruction and it requires access to memory, which is, in most of cases, much slower.  Actually, for me gcc generated `movaps` and `mov`, but it's the same. Also, I tried running small performance test, it works even slower than `_mm_extract_epi64`.

Comment: @alexo_o, thanks for checking this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On x86-64 you can use `_mm_cvtsi128_si64`, which translates to a single `MOVQ r64, xmm` instruction

Answer (score 1):

One possibility might be to use `MOVDQ2Q`, which has a latency of 2 instructions on Piledriver:

```
static inline int64_t extractlo_64(const __m128i v)
{
    return _m_to_int64(_mm_movepi64_pi64(v)); // MOVDQ2Q + MOVQ
}
```

Comment: That indeed improved my results on performance tests. However, [Intel intrinsic guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/) (I haven't found information from AMD) says that '_m_to_int64' generates `movq r64, mm` which has a latency of 5 cycles. Though, ILP helps here, I guess.

Comment: The generated code is somewhat compiler-dependent - I looked at gcc, clang and ICC and they were all different. But I think overall it's a small win, whichever compiler you use. (Also note that for gcc and clang `_m_to_int64` can just be an `(int64_t)` cast, although this probably doesn't affect the generated code.)

Comment: Agner Fog's insn table for Piledriver lists `movd r32/r64, mm/x` as 8 cycle latency.  Going through an mmx register isn't necessary for avoiding `pextrq`.  I'm sure you knew that, but you don't say anything about why this 2 insn sequence might be better than just `movq`.  I assume the thinking is that `movq` from an mmx reg is faster, but Agner Fog's table doesn't indicate that.

Comment: @PeterCordes: actually I'm slightly out of my depth when it comes to AMD CPUs. I'm surprised that a register-to-register move could have an 8 cycle latency though.

Comment: Yeah, I don't have any AMD CPUs on hand, and haven't given much thought to optimizing for them either.  But yes, data movement between GP and vector regs has MASSIVE latency according to Agner Fog's tables.  It's not just one insn that might be a fluke.  It's only half as bad (4 cycles) in Steamroller.  Going from GP to ivec is 5 / 10 cycles (bulldozer / steamroller)!  It may be faster to store to memory and rely on store-forwarding.

Comment: I think the main reason gp<->vector moves are so slow is that Bulldozer/Piledriver/Steamroller shares a vector unit between every pair of two cores in a cluster.  (This is why AMD CPUs advertise themselves as 8-core, while Intel CPUs advertise as 4-core with hyperthreading.)